# Do something when user creates post (that's pending)

Tags: functions, email, actions, post-status

How do i do something when a (normal) user creates a post (that is submitted for approval)

I currently have:

```
function emailinvestment( $new_status, $old_status, $post_id ) {

        if ( $old_status != 'new' && $new_status != 'pending' ) {

            // Do something (not working atm)

        }
    }

    add_action('transition_post_status','emailinvestment', 10,3);
```

Thanks for taking a look at this one :)

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the hook not fire at all? Are your conditions wrong (inside the `if`)? Does you code (not posted) inside the `if` not work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it! The following line:

```
if ( $old_status != 'new' && $new_status != 'pending' ) {
```

Should be:

```
if ( $old_status != 'new' && $new_status == 'pending' ) {
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Funny how this post gets a minus 1, i'm the topic starter and this code works lol

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target only one specific status change is probably easy / efficient use the
`{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}` filter, in your case:

```
add_action('draft-to-pending', 'do_something');
add_action('auto-draft-to-pending', 'do_something');

function do_something ( $post ) {
  // do something with the $post object
}
```

Comment: For some reason the action does not fire at all using this method.

Comment: I have some doubts that actions don't fires... how have you debug that? Are you sure that the problem is not in your `do_something` function?

Comment: Got it working, check my own answer that has -1 :p

Comment: @CasvanDongen I don't now why your own answer got -1, and is reasonable that it works, but if it works my solution should work too, it only doesn't work if the post is setted to pending _after_ be pubblished. However, if your solution work, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can't mark it yet, i'll have to wait 24 hours before i can accept my own answer. Thanks :)